# All string are "???" while retrieving tables from Oracle of object type

Tags: java, oracle, struct

When I try to retrieve an object type from Oracle procedure I recieve correct numbers however all strings that this procedure passes to me are "???".
My example:

```
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.sql.Types;

public class InitMethod {

    public static void init() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.20:1521:dw", "user", "password");

        final String typeName = "T_DEMO_OBJECT";
        final String typeTableName = "T_DEMO_OBJECTS";

        final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName.toUpperCase(), connection);
        final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();

        CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call p_generate_demo_objects(?, ?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, 7);

        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);
        cs.execute();

        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cs.getObject(2)).getArray();
        for (Object tmp : data) {
            Struct row = (Struct) tmp;

            int idx = 1;
            for (Object attribute : row
                    .getAttributes()) {
                System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(idx) + " = " + attribute);
                ++idx;
            }
            System.out.println("---");
        }
        cs.close();
}
```

I receive correct numbers however all strings are "???":

> SOME_NUMBER = 1 SOME_STRING = ???
>
> SOME_NUMBER = 2 SOME_STRING = ???

What might be an issue?

(I use ojdbc6.jar)

Comment: It is still uknown case. I tried this exact code in our production system and it works properly. Before this I executed the code in my small testing project. I don't understand right now what is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you don't include orai18n.jar in your classpath and when the database character set is not in this list: ASCII, UTF8 or ISOLATIN1. All the characters are replaced with the "replacement character" which is '?'. You can download orai18n.jar from OTN (search for "oracle jdbc download" in google).

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we have columns of PII data in certain Oracle database schema that are redacted and replaced by a custom string. It seems likely that the '???' sequence to be a data redaction in the table. You might check with your DB Admin to see if this is the case.

Comment: Ok. I’ll try this. Thanks.